# mod_rewrite to chop off query string

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite

My urls look like this:

```
(something).php?kid=[someNumber]
```

e.g.

```
index.php?kid=9
```

or

```
abc.php?kid=23
```

I use these numbers to query a database to create a submenu.

How can I change the url so that the query string is not visible but I can still query the database?

my approach:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond      %{QUERY_STRING}    ^kid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule      (.*)               $1?     [R=permanent]
```

It does chop off the query string but the database query doesnt work anymore.

How can I do that?

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: "__How can I do that?__" you don't.

Comment: No way to beautify the url and still have the $_GET receive something??

Comment: As I said before, no, you cannot do that. How would apache know which values to pass ?!

Comment: I thought it was just rewriting the url but keeping the original one somehow... oh, well, nevermind then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mustn't - but if you really want...:)  Put value in cookie

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^kid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^ - [co=kid:%1:%{HTTP_HOST}:7200:/]
# This Cond to avoid endless redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*)  $1?  [R=permanent]
```

ask `example.com/Thsng?kid=12345`then in php:

```
session_start();
echo '$_COOKIE["kid"]; // echo 12345
```